# How to call the setTileDecoder() method of TileView Library (moagrius)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, view, decoder

Can someone help me to know how to call the `setTileDecoder()` method of TileView Library (moagrius) by passing our own custom decoder .

Answer (score 0):

You create your own class that implements `BitmapDecoder` (https://github.com/moagrius/TileView/blob/master/src/com/qozix/tileview/graphics/BitmapDecoder.java), then pass in an instance to `TileView.setTileDecoder`.

There's a wiki page here: https://github.com/moagrius/TileView/wiki/Tile-Sources

Answer (score 0):

Assume you already have codes to load the tiles from asset folder, now you want to convert it to load from file directory and all you have to do is....create a custom BitmapDecoder and add a line of code.

After you created your custom class which implements BitmapDecoder and has a function call decode and return you a bitmap

```
public class BitmapDecodeFileDirectory implements BitmapDecoder
```

You call the setDecoder like this

```
String whateverYourPath = getFilesDir().toString()
tileView.setDecoder(new BitmapDecodeFileDirectory());
tileView.addDetailLevel(1.000f, whateverYourPath);
```